# I'm writing a code in Java, but when I compile, the Error: “.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.” comes up

Tags: java, compiler-errors

The prompt for the code I am writing is:

This assignment involves writing a program that models a super hero. A super hero has a name, wears a special suit when performing hero duties, might wear a cape, and has a birth date. A super hero is also able to invoke his/her special powers when called on to do so.

Implement a class named SuperHero that models the above description. Use a Name class to represent the name attribute, and a Date class to represent the birth date attribute. You may use the Date class from the lectures or define your own. If the super hero is wearing their special suit, then the suit attribute should indicate this. Similarly, if the super hero is wearing a cape, then a cape attribute should indicate this. String types can be used for these two attributes. There should also be an attribute that indicates whether the super hero is invoking their special powers, and a method to set and unset the special powers attribute. Provide appropriate class constructors, getter methods, setter methods, and any other methods you think are necessary to model a super hero.

Write a main method that creates an array of SuperHero objects and displays their attributes and displays whether their super powers are being invoked.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Name
{
  String name;

  public String Name() //Name(String name)
  {
    this.name=name;
    return this.name;
  }

  public String getName()
  {

    return name;
  }
}

public class SuperHero 
{
  String cape,suit,specialPowers,name,dob;

  public static void main(String args[])

  {

    int insuper=0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many superheros would you like");

    insuper = sc.nextInt();

    SuperHero[] sh=new SuperHero[insuper];

    for(int i=0;i<insuper;i++)

    {

      System.out.println("Specify features to the Super Hero "+(i+1)+" That you want for them" );

      System.out.println("Name : ");

      Name n=new Name(sc.next());

      sh[i].name=n.getName();

      System.out.println("Date of Birth");

      Date dd = new Date(sc.next());

      sh[i].dob=dd.toString();

      System.out.println("will he have a cape: (y/n)");

      String ch=sc.next();

      if (ch.charAt(0) == 'y' || ch.charAt(0) == 'Y') 

        sh[i].cape = "yes";

      else 

        sh[i].cape = "no";


      System.out.println("Will he have a suit: (y/n)");

      ch=sc.next();

      if(ch.charAt(0) == 'y' || ch.charAt(0) == 'Y')

        sh[i].suit = "yes";

      else

        sh[i].suit = "no";

      System.out.println("Will he have super powers (y/n)");

      ch=sc.next();

      if(ch.charAt(0) == 'y' || ch.charAt(0) == 'Y')
      {
        sh[i].seSuperPowers();
      }

      else
        sh[i].unSetSuperPowers();
    }

    for(int i=0;i<insuper;i++)

    {

      System.out.println("Super man "+(i+1)+" consist of these features");

      System.out.println("Name : "+sh[i].name);

      System.out.println("Date of birth : "+sh[i].dob);

      System.out.println("Suit : "+sh[i].cape);

      System.out.println("Powers : "+sh[i].getSuperPowers());

    }

  }


  void seSuperPowers()
  {
    specialPowers = "yes";
  }


  void unSetSuperPowers()
  {
    specialPowers = "no";
  }


  String getSuperPowers()
  {
    return specialPowers;
  }

}
```

Whenever I compile, this error comes up:

```
    Note: SuperHero.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Could anyone please help me, re-write or edit the code, it will be much appreciated?

Comment: That's not an error, it's a "warning". Does the program work?

Comment: As the message says: "Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.", but ir probably refers to your use of [this Date constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date-java.lang.String-).

Comment: The [`Date(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)) constructor has been deprecated since Java 1.1 (a _really_ long time ago). The documentation tells you what to use instead.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, it is a warning not an error and if that is the only thing, it should compile fine. When running the compiler with the flag -Xlint, it should reveal that the Date(String) constructor for the java.util.Data class has been depreciated (meaning that it should no longer be used)

But you should also be getting an error when you try to create

```
Name n=new Name(sc.next());
```

Since you never defined a constructor with the format Name(string). If the assignment forces you to use a wrapper class for the name field, I would instead of creating a string instance variable in the SuperHero class, create an instance of the Name class defined above, otherwise using it seems redundant. Of course, to do that you will need to create a new constructor for the Name class that takes a string as a parameter. I would do the same for the Date class and the date of birth for each SuperHero (minus creating the new constructor).

Comment: Could you please show me an example of how I would create an instance of the name class?

Comment: Instead of `String cape,suit,specialPowers,name,dob;` It could be `String cape, suit; Name name; Date dob;` Of course you would then assign these values to new objects  when needed.